# Getting Path information out of an alias in Powershell

Tags: powershell

If I try to lookup `vi` on my machine it gives me this:

```
❯ get-command vi

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           vi -> vim.exe
```

However, `vim.exe` isn't on the PATH. The alias does, however, work, so I feel like there's more information on the alias that would provide more information. How do I obtain the path to `vim.exe` from the alias?

Comment: how did you check vim.exe not in the PATH? did you try to just run `vim.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1st resolve the alias

```
$cmdInfo = get-command vi
```

#2nd get the command info, add fl* to list all properties

```
get-command $cmdInfo.ReferencedCommand | fl *
```

Comment: Thankyou. That didn't quite work, but this did: `(get-command vi).ReferencedCommand.Source` and I wouldn't have found that without your answer, so I'll accept your answer.